# Why can't I open the 'Graphics/Performance Options' menu (greyed out) in The Sims 2?

Tags: the-sims-2

I recently installed The Sims 2 Ultimate Collection from Origin, I can't access the *Graphics/Performance Options* menu.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.leefish.nl/mybb/showthread.php?tid=6882) and added my video card to *Video Cards.sgr*. There was no "NOT FOUND IN DATABASE!" error in my *-config-log.txt* file, but I still can't access the menu.

This is the menu I am talking about:

[image: Menu option]

**Specs:**
*OS: Windows 10

CPU: Intel Core i7-4870HQ @ 2.50GHz

RAM: 16 GB

GPU: AMD Radeon R9 M370X*

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the *Graphics/Performance Options* menu from the Tutorial. Go to a lot in an actual neighborhood and you should be able to access the menu from there.